# Is there a way to open SublimeText 2 From Other Applications

Tags: sublimetext

I loved the ability to open a file in textmate from other applications using the `txmt://open/?url=file://` command.  I can't seem to find anything similar for SublimeText 2, does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subl-handler is an app that maps textmate's txmt url protocol to Sublime Text. I haven't tried it myself, but looks like it's what you're looking for.

Available here: https://github.com/hiddenbek/subl-handler

(Side note: for windows users, there's this: https://bitbucket.org/sublimator/sublimeprotocol/src/)

Comment: github repo went 404. Some forks are still available:
https://github.com/asuth/subl-handler
https://github.com/aMoniker/subl-handler

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system are you using?

If you are on the Windows OS this is easy enough to do by registering the file extension with the Windows Shell and then using the *ShellExecute* WIN32 API.

Comment: I'm on OSX and I have subl registered in bash.  But lets say I wanted to call it from the browser like you can with textmate using a bit of code like the snippet in my question.  I'd like to integrate that with my favorite unit testing framework.